# Deploying Postgres DB in Azure Container App

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, pgadmin-4, azure-container-apps

Hi I am new to Azure and I got a requirement to deploy Postgres DB to Azure Container app. I know its not a good practice to host a DB inside a containerize environment.

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/quickstart-portal) from the Microsoft documentation to deploy the app and following are my configurations,

[image]

I created a VNET since I need to select TCP as the Ingress type and mapped the target port and and exposed port port as 5432 to 5432

[image]

After I deploy the application and try to connect to the DB using Pgadmin I am getting the following error.

[image]

I want to make sure the Postgres DB running successfully inside the Azure Container App and need to connect from Pgadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

- Your app definition is incorrect (particularly around "Command override")
- You could fix that part and Postgres would start, but you will run into a persistent storage issue. Azure ContainerApps today only supports [AzureFiles SMB shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts?pivots=aca-cli) for persistent storage. However, [Postgres requires hardlinks](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/548#issuecomment-1001513872) and [AzureFiles SMB doesn't support hardlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/features-not-supported-by-the-azure-file-service). So you won't be able to mount a persistent storage that works for postgres. Once ContainerApps can mount AzureFiles NFS shares, this will work.

Regarding the first problem, the "Command override" is for overriding the command running in your docker image, not the docker command itself.

So those values will need to be put in the environment variables section below:

like:

[image]

or using the azure cli

```bash
az containerapp create \
  --name $POSTGRES_INSTANCE_NAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT  \
  --image docker.io/postgres:15 \
  --secrets pgpass="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" \
  --env-vars POSTGRES_USER="$POSTGRES_USER" POSTGRES_DB="$POSTGRES_DB" POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secretref:pgpass \
  --transport tcp \
  --target-port 5432 \
  --ingress external \
  --min-replicas 1 \
  --max-replicas 1
```

you could change `--ingress external` to `--ingress internal` then deploy pgadmin on the same environment. Then pgadmin should be able to reach postgres on `$POSTGRES_INSTANCE_NAME:5432`

to deploy pgadmin

```bash
az containerapp create \
  --name pgadmin \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT  \
  --image dpage/pgadmin4:6.15 \
  --secrets pgpass="$PGADMIN_PASSWORD" \
  --env-vars PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="$PGADMIN_EMAIL" PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT="8080" PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=secretref:pgpass \
  --transport http \
  --target-port 8080 \
  --ingress external \
  --min-replicas 1 \
  --max-replicas 1
```

Comment: Hi @ahmelsayed Thanks for the quick answer I could able to connect to the PgAdmin one more thing If I want to pass override command via cli how could I do it

Comment: Hi, I'm deploying a postgres container for my app. I'm just curious, which would be the better approach of the two scenarios you suggested? Deploy the database instance with ingress external, or deploy the database instance with ingress internal and deploy another container for pgadmin with ingress external? Is one approach better than the other from a security standpoint? In terms of cost the second one is worse because you are paying for two containers now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, MS has since updated their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/tutorial-dev-services-postgresql?tabs=bicep#binding-to-the-dev-service) with examples for deploying an [instance](https://hub.docker.com/r/sosedoff/pgweb/#!) of [pgweb](https://github.com/sosedoff/pgweb) (the "Simple web-based and cross platform PostgreSQL database explorer").

The documentation currently (1/2024) advises "See Bicep or azd example", which contains the following [bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep) file (`postgres-dev.bicep`)...

```
resource pgweb 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-04-01-preview' = {
  name: 'pgweb'
  location: location
  properties: {
    environmentId: appEnvironment.id
    configuration: {
      ingress: {
        external: true
        targetPort: 8081
      }
    }
    template: {
      serviceBinds: [
        {
          serviceId: postgres.id
          name: 'postgres'
        }
      ]
      containers: [
        {
          name: 'pgweb'
          image: 'docker.io/sosedoff/pgweb:latest'
          command: [
            '/bin/sh'
          ]
          args: [
            '-c'
            'PGWEB_DATABASE_URL=$POSTGRES_URL /usr/bin/pgweb --bind=0.0.0.0 --listen=8081'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

output pgwebUrl string = 'https://${pgweb.properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn}'
```

"Deploy the bicep template with the... command."

```
az deployment group create -g $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --query 'properties.outputs.*.value' \
    --template-file postgres-dev.bicep
```

"The Bicep command returns a URL. Copy this URL to your browser to visit the deployed site."